# How to open a binary file, read objects and place them into the array list?

Tags: java, serialization, binaryfiles

Consider the following class definition for an item sold at a supermarket / food shop:

There is a binary data file named “objects.dat” containing the details of 5 objects of type GroceryItem that were previously in memory before being saved directly to the data file.
    Write code for a method named processFiles which will open the “objects.dat” file, read in the 5 individual GroceryItem objects, placing them into an ArrayList. Then, it will create a text file named “report.txt”, and write the barcode, name, and price of each GroceryItem out to the file, one GroceryItem per line. Include appropriate exception handling code, to display user-friendly messages when things go wrong.

Comment: Could you show us what you have done so far?

Comment: This is an old exam question.

Comment: And a very poor one, if that's all there is to it. You should have been told how the file was created. And if the file already exists, why are you being asked why `implements Serializable` is now necessary? On the first line of what?

Comment: Your edit doesn't address any of that, and jjust turns this into a homework question. This is not a homework service.

Answer (score -1):

I understand by your question that you want to read binary data and store in array.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Path test_path = Paths.get("D:/test", "test.txt");

    try {
      byte[] testArray = Files.readAllBytes(test_path );

      String wikiString = new String(testArray , "ISO-8859-1");
      System.out.println(testArray );
    } catch (IOException io) {
      System.out.println(io);
    }

  }
```

Comment: I don't know how you got from 'read in the 5 individual GroceryItem objects' to 'read binary data and store in array', but you're completely wrong.